# Multiple input in for loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, input

I have to write a programme in c++ where user enters a number N, then on a second line he enters as many numbers as N, no more. The ouput shoud be the sum of all positive numbers among the entered numbers.
I have to use for loop. Also we have not covered much so far, only if statements.

The code I have tried gives the sum of positive numbers only, but I can't make the programme use N inputs and stop. It either calculates only one or continues as long as user enters numbers.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n, sum=0;
    cin>> n;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter numbers"<<endl;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cin>>i;
        if(i>0)
    {sum=sum+i;
    }
 cout<<sum<<endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the same variable, as the loop counter in `cin>>i;`? Why don't you use different variable for read value?

Comment: Code works just fine here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/naZfBzsuB3Hj3itO

Comment: Unrelated: Prefer `for (int i=0; i<n; i++)` to `for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)` because everything in C++ starts at 0 and runs to n-1. Forcing origin 1 indexing will cause a great many problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same variable (`i`) for looping and input.

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
        cin>>i;
```

Whatever gets entered in that `cin>>i` ruins the logic of your program. Add one separate input variable and keep your `i` for the loop.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n, sum = 0;
    std::cout << "How many numbers do you want to enter? \n";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Enter numbers: \n";
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        std::cout << i << ": ";

        int input;
        if(std::cin >> input) {
            if(input > 0) {
                sum = sum + input;
            }
            std::cout << sum << std::endl;
        } else
            break; // user failed to enter a number
    }
}
```

Comment: When I said "_Whatever gets entered ..._" I meant "_there is only one number that would **not** ruin the logic of your program and it has the value `i` in every iteration_" - I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it. I am a beginner, we study this at school, maths high school, and this stuff is not easy for  5th grade. we only have two hous a week, not enough.

Comment: @Imemi You're welcome! It's great that you study this in 5:th grade! It never stops being fun, promise! (... and as always, a disclaimer: there are rumours about people who liked programming and now don't - rumours)